# Jboss.xml ignoring context-root

Tags: web-services, jboss5.x

I was trying to set up context-root element for my webservice in jboss 5.0 and it is ignoring it during deployment. Here is the sample xml which I am using, all i need is just context-root

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss_5_0.xsd">
    <webservices>
        <context-root>/MyWebService</context-root>
    </webservices>
</jboss>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be beacuse of attributes of your  tag.
Try w/o it.